# Impute time series using similar time series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, missing-data, forecasting, imputation

I have a problem where I have a lot of data about 1 year recordings of thermostats where every hour it gives me the mean temperature in that household. But a lot of data is not available due to they only installed the thermostat in the middle of the year or they put out the thermostat for a week or ... But a lot of this thermostat data is really similar. What I want to do is impute the missing data using similar timeseries.

So lets say house A only started in july but from there they are very similar to household B I would want to then use the info from household B to predict what the data dould be before july in house A.

I was thinking about training a Recurrent Neural Network that could do this for me but I am not shure what is out there to do this and when I search for papers and such they almost exclusively work on data sets over multiple years and impute the data using the data of previous years. I do not have this data, so that is not an option.

Does anyone have a clue how to tackle this problem or a refference I could use that solves a similar problem ?

Comment: Could you please share some data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you want to impute the data using cross-sectional data rather than time series information.

There are actually quite a lot of imputation packages that can do this for you in R. (if you are using R)

You'd need equally spaced data. So 1 values per hour and if it is not present, then it needs to be NA. So ideally you have then multiple time series of qual length.

Then you merge these time series according to the time stamp / hour.

Afterwards you can apply an imputation package like e.g.  `mice`, `missForest`, `imputeR` with basically one line of code. These packages will use the correlations between the different time series to estimate the missing values in these series.